# How to select a specific element according to a text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the css of an element based only on the title value. I would like to be able to change only the css property of the button where the title is **This one**. I can't modify the HTML.

```css
.x-window > .x-window-bl > .x-window-br > .x-window-bc > .x-window-footer > .x-panel-fbar > .x-toolbar-ct > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > .x-toolbar-right-row > .x-toolbar-cell > table > .x-btn-small > tr > td:nth-child(2) > em > button{
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<div id="ext-comp-1063" class=" x-window x-window-plain x-resizable-pinned">
   <div class="x-window-tl">
      <div class="x-window-tr">
         <div class="x-window-tc">
            <div class="x-window-header x-unselectable x-panel-icon x-deluge-remove-window-icon x-window-draggable" id="ext-gen215">
               <div class="x-tool x-tool-close" id="ext-gen221">&nbsp;</div>
               <span class="x-window-header-text" id="ext-gen226">This one</span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="x-window-bl" id="ext-gen219">
      <div class="x-window-br">
         <div class="x-window-bc">
            <div class="x-window-footer x-panel-btns" id="ext-gen218" style="width: 328px;">
               <div id="ext-comp-1064" class="x-panel-fbar x-small-editor x-toolbar-layout-ct" style="width: auto;">
                  <table cellspacing="0" class="x-toolbar-ct">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td class="x-toolbar-right" align="right">
                              <table cellspacing="0" class="x-toolbar-right-ct">
                                 <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td>
                                          <table cellspacing="0">
                                             <tbody>
                                                <tr class="x-toolbar-right-row">
                                                   <td class="x-toolbar-cell" id="ext-gen227">
                                                      <table id="ext-comp-1065" cellspacing="0" class="x-btn x-btn-noicon" style="width: auto;">
                                                         <tbody class="x-btn-small x-btn-icon-small-left">
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <td class="x-btn-ml"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
                                                               <td class="x-btn-mc"><em class="" unselectable="on"><button type="button" id="ext-gen228" class=" x-btn-text">Cancel</button></em></td>
                                                               <td class="x-btn-mr"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                         </tbody>
                                                      </table>
                                                   </td>
                                                </tr>
                                             </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </tbody>
                              </table>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="ext-comp-1063" class=" x-window x-window-plain x-resizable-pinned">
   <div class="x-window-tl">
      <div class="x-window-tr">
         <div class="x-window-tc">
            <div class="x-window-header x-unselectable x-panel-icon x-deluge-remove-window-icon x-window-draggable" id="ext-gen215">
               <div class="x-tool x-tool-close" id="ext-gen221">&nbsp;</div>
               <span class="x-window-header-text" id="ext-gen226">Not this one</span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="x-window-bl" id="ext-gen219">
      <div class="x-window-br">
         <div class="x-window-bc">
            <div class="x-window-footer x-panel-btns" id="ext-gen218" style="width: 328px;">
               <div id="ext-comp-1064" class="x-panel-fbar x-small-editor x-toolbar-layout-ct" style="width: auto;">
                  <table cellspacing="0" class="x-toolbar-ct">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td class="x-toolbar-right" align="right">
                              <table cellspacing="0" class="x-toolbar-right-ct">
                                 <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td>
                                          <table cellspacing="0">
                                             <tbody>
                                                <tr class="x-toolbar-right-row">
                                                   <td class="x-toolbar-cell" id="ext-gen227">
                                                      <table id="ext-comp-1065" cellspacing="0" class="x-btn x-btn-noicon" style="width: auto;">
                                                         <tbody class="x-btn-small x-btn-icon-small-left">
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <td class="x-btn-ml"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
                                                               <td class="x-btn-mc"><em class="" unselectable="on"><button type="button" id="ext-gen228" class=" x-btn-text">Cancel</button></em></td>
                                                               <td class="x-btn-mr"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                         </tbody>
                                                      </table>
                                                   </td>
                                                </tr>
                                             </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </tbody>
                              </table>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Why is it a duplicate ? The data contained in the title isn't on the same layer of the button

Comment: Quick JS fix will work here! But would like to follow on to this if we can get this done with CSS.

Comment: Even with JS how would you acheive it ?

Comment: @executable This is possible with JavaScript

Comment: I added tags `javascript` and `jquery`

Comment: It got a duplicate, but I had spent some time on this. Please refer https://codepen.io/satyamqainfotech/pen/ebRXdM

Comment: Can you explain what this line do ? `let buttonContainer = b.closest('.c').nextSibling.nextSibling`

Comment: Here is how you can utilize the dupe link logic with javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/nq9od431/

Comment: @executable The `nextSibling` finds both text and element nodes, you should use what I suggested in my fiddle, `nextElementSibling`.

Comment: @executable I closed it as a dupe as one can't do what you asked with CSS. As you then added script to your tags list, I decided to both post a solution in  a comment, and have also now added one more dupe links, which shows a similar solution. Do you find it okay with that?

Comment: Yep thank you for your answer

Answer (score -1):

You can use `data attribute` like this to achieve same result

```css
[data-content="this one"] {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div data-content="this one">This one</div>
<div data-content="not this one">Not This one</div>
```

I have change your demo a bit with above code see https://jsfiddle.net/8th9xrm5/

Comment: Yes but I can't change the HTML. You can check data in css with `contains(text)`

Comment: what I gave you is logic, see my updated answer I have provided solution in your code, but yes you have to add data attribute to make it work

Comment: `contains(text)` is in jquery you cant do this in css only

Comment: Oh right, thank you to point it out

Answer (score -1):

Use `first-child`

```css
.x-window:first-child .x-window-bl > .x-window-br > .x-window-bc > .x-window-footer > .x-panel-fbar > .x-toolbar-ct > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > .x-toolbar-right-row > .x-toolbar-cell > table > .x-btn-small > tr > td:nth-child(2) > em > button{
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<div id="ext-comp-1063" class=" x-window x-window-plain x-resizable-pinned">
   <div class="x-window-tl">
      <div class="x-window-tr">
         <div class="x-window-tc">
            <div class="x-window-header x-unselectable x-panel-icon x-deluge-remove-window-icon x-window-draggable" id="ext-gen215">
               <div class="x-tool x-tool-close" id="ext-gen221">&nbsp;</div>
               <span class="x-window-header-text" id="ext-gen226">This one</span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="x-window-bl" id="ext-gen219">
      <div class="x-window-br">
         <div class="x-window-bc">
            <div class="x-window-footer x-panel-btns" id="ext-gen218" style="width: 328px;">
               <div id="ext-comp-1064" class="x-panel-fbar x-small-editor x-toolbar-layout-ct" style="width: auto;">
                  <table cellspacing="0" class="x-toolbar-ct">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td class="x-toolbar-right" align="right">
                              <table cellspacing="0" class="x-toolbar-right-ct">
                                 <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td>
                                          <table cellspacing="0">
                                             <tbody>
                                                <tr class="x-toolbar-right-row">
                                                   <td class="x-toolbar-cell" id="ext-gen227">
                                                      <table id="ext-comp-1065" cellspacing="0" class="x-btn x-btn-noicon" style="width: auto;">
                                                         <tbody class="x-btn-small x-btn-icon-small-left">
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <td class="x-btn-ml"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
                                                               <td class="x-btn-mc"><em class="" unselectable="on"><button type="button" id="ext-gen228" class=" x-btn-text">Cancel</button></em></td>
                                                               <td class="x-btn-mr"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                         </tbody>
                                                      </table>
                                                   </td>
                                                </tr>
                                             </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </tbody>
                              </table>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="ext-comp-1063" class=" x-window x-window-plain x-resizable-pinned">
   <div class="x-window-tl">
      <div class="x-window-tr">
         <div class="x-window-tc">
            <div class="x-window-header x-unselectable x-panel-icon x-deluge-remove-window-icon x-window-draggable" id="ext-gen215">
               <div class="x-tool x-tool-close" id="ext-gen221">&nbsp;</div>
               <span class="x-window-header-text" id="ext-gen226">Not this one</span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="x-window-bl" id="ext-gen219">
      <div class="x-window-br">
         <div class="x-window-bc">
            <div class="x-window-footer x-panel-btns" id="ext-gen218" style="width: 328px;">
               <div id="ext-comp-1064" class="x-panel-fbar x-small-editor x-toolbar-layout-ct" style="width: auto;">
                  <table cellspacing="0" class="x-toolbar-ct">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td class="x-toolbar-right" align="right">
                              <table cellspacing="0" class="x-toolbar-right-ct">
                                 <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td>
                                          <table cellspacing="0">
                                             <tbody>
                                                <tr class="x-toolbar-right-row">
                                                   <td class="x-toolbar-cell" id="ext-gen227">
                                                      <table id="ext-comp-1065" cellspacing="0" class="x-btn x-btn-noicon" style="width: auto;">
                                                         <tbody class="x-btn-small x-btn-icon-small-left">
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <td class="x-btn-ml"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
                                                               <td class="x-btn-mc"><em class="" unselectable="on"><button type="button" id="ext-gen228" class=" x-btn-text">Cancel</button></em></td>
                                                               <td class="x-btn-mr"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                         </tbody>
                                                      </table>
                                                   </td>
                                                </tr>
                                             </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </tbody>
                              </table>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In my case I don't know on which position it would be. I can only get the element depending on the title

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve that with JavaScript like that:

```
<script>
getElementsByContains = function(str,elmtTagName="*",node=document){
  var elms = document.evaluate( "//"+elmtTagName+"[contains(., '" +str+ "')]" ,node, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null ), nodeSet = [];
  for ( var i=0 ; i < elms.snapshotLength; i++ ){  
    nodeSet.push(elms.snapshotItem(i));
  }
return nodeSet;
}
getElementsByContains('Cancel','button')[0].style.background ='red';

</script>
```

modified from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37156888/6525081).

Comment: I don't understand how you get by the title value

Comment: Sorry i probably misread/misunderstand the question.

Comment: I don't know the position in my code (it's dynamic), I only know the title value